# How to delete selected documents in search result xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a search view xpages. Everything ok except to delete selected document(s) using xp:deleteselectedDocuments tag from the search result.

```
<xp:button value="Delete" id="button4">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="viewPanel1">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:deleteSelectedDocuments view="viewPanel1" message="Do you really want to delete these documents?">
            </xp:deleteSelectedDocuments>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

How i am going to do that?

If delete from non-search result view, no problem. I am able to delete document.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add your code that shows how you use xp:deleteselectedDocuments in the search view.

Comment: <xp:button value="Delete" id="button4">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="viewPanel1">
<xp:this.action>
 <xp:deleteSelectedDocuments view="viewPanel1"
  message="Do you really want to delete these documents?">
 </xp:deleteSelectedDocuments>
</xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>

Comment: Did you try with *refreshMode="complete"* ? Does that work, despite the fact that it does a full refresh that you probably don't want?

Comment: Not worked. I am wondering that delete tag; (deleteselectedDocuments) only supported for non-search view.